# Generating separate consecutive Note entries with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Suppose I'm writing a Doxygen comment like so

```
/**
 * \brief Foo
 * \details FooFooBar
 * \note Note1 goes here
 * \note Note2 goes here
 */
```

Note1 and Note2 are rendered as two paragraph of the same Note section. I would like them to the two separated Note sections one after the other. How can I achieve this? Using curly braces and extra line breaks did not do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap each `\note` in a `\parblock`..`\endparblock` like so:

```
/**
 * \brief Foo
 * \details FooFooBar
 * \parblock
 * \note Note1 goes here
 * \endparblock
 * \parblock
 * \note Note2 goes here
 * \endparblock
 */
```